# Recyclerview show only fully visible items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to implement the recyclerview in which upon scrolling, only the fully visible items are shown like in play store.

If the next element doesn't have the required space to be fully visible, it will be hided.

Comment: Use `SnapHelper` for recyclerview.

Comment: yep, most likely: `LinearSnapHelper`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SnapHelper is used for such a situation

```
RecyclerView list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(list);
```